# npm Warning : prefer global coffee-script@1.10.0 should be installed with -g

Tags: angularjs, npm

These type of warning messages are displaying when installing angular packages through npm. Also displaying marked@0.3.5, jshint@2.8.0, leasot@1.3.2, node-gyp@3.2.1.

I am using

> node v4.2.3
>
> npm 3.5.0
>
> angular 1.4.8

How can i solve this warning messages?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it globally:

```
npm install coffee-script -g
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.